# how to call url parameter day month year in laravel

Tags: laravel

I want to call the parameter {day} / {date} / {year} in the url, but it doesn't work, this is my parameter code, I'm very confused please help me
[image]

Comment: Plz show me your params with for example `dd($day, $date, $year)` before your query.

Comment: if I do dd {day} {date} {year} the results are empty, please help me @Immeyti

Comment: Show us what URL do you use to access it.

Comment: @JCode Route::get('/data', function () {

$data = [
'day'=>date('d'),
'month'=>date('M'),
'year'=>date('Y')
];

$tgl = $data['year'].'-'.$data['month'].'-'.$data['day'];

$a = App\permintaan_brg::select('id','nama_brg','tanggal')
->whereDay('tanggal','=',$tgl);
 dd($a);
//return view('video', compact('a',$a));
});

Comment: always post your code. not image

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```php
Route::get('a/{day}/{month}/{year}', function ($day, $month, $year) {

    $users = App\User::whereDay('created_at',$day)
        ->whereMonth('created_at', $month)
        ->whereYear('created_at', $year)->get();

    return view('your-view', compact('users', 'day', 'month', 'year'))
});
```

You should follow variables order.
your problem is that you pass `day` in URL params to `$year` param and vice-versa.

Comment: i try this                                                                                          
Route::get('/data', function () {

$data = [
'day'=>date('d'),
'month'=>date('M'),
'year'=>date('Y')
];

$tgl = $data['year'].'-'.$data['month'].'-'.$data['day'];

$a = App\permintaan_brg::select('id','nama_brg','tanggal')
->whereDay('tanggal','=',$tgl);
 return dd($a);  
I have data in the database, how to call day month and year in view

});

Comment: I don't understand your purpose. your question is different from this comment.

Comment: Initially I used the method as you described, but failed ... that's why I used another method @Immeyti

Comment: PLZ explain what do you want to do?

Comment: If I use your method, how do I call day month year in view? thank you

Comment: Updated my answer for call day, month and year variable in view

Comment: ok i try your way, how do you call the route? do i have to foreach? sorry I just learned to use laravel @Immeyti

Comment: If my answer is correct for your question plz accept it. if you want more help to connect with me or open a new question.